# Use of unresolved identifier, recognizing 2 different pickerViews containing the same information. In Swift

Tags: swift

I am farely new at proggraming and I am trying to build an app, but I cant figure out how to fix my problem. All the help is gladly appreciated!!!!

So in my app there are 2 pickerViews and each pickerView contains the same information. My problem is that I would like to acces the information from  both of them, then connect it to Google or Yahoo to find the right calculation between the 2, and display that calculation at the bottom of the display.

What I have done is use the function didSelectRow for pickerView, and I added a modal alert so that when I scroll through the pickerView I can tell that the function is working, however it does that for both of the pickerViews and I want both of the pickerViews to be completely seperate functions.

My main problem is that I cant access the data from the didSelectRow so that I can do my calculations in another function (I've set up a function to handle the calculations/conversions with a placeholder multiplier, until I connect it to an API). I know that the data from that function is out of scope (that's the error the compiler is giving me) but I cant figure out how to access the information, I have been searching for a couple of weeks.

Thank You So Much!!!! All the help is gladly appreciated!!!!!
Ps. This is in Swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create `@IBOutlet`s to your two pickerViews:

```
@IBOutlet weak var picker1: UIPickerView!
@IBOutlet weak var picker2: UIPickerView!
```

you can access the selected row for each with:

```
let row1 = picker1.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
let row2 = picker2.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
```

You can then use those as indices into the arrays that are supplying the data for your pickers.

As an example, I created a view with two pickers and I print the sum whenever one of the pickers changes:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var picker1: UIPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var picker2: UIPickerView!

    var data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        let sum = data[picker1.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)] + data[picker2.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
        print(sum)
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return String(data[row])
    }
}
```

Comment: I have exactly what you have there, except for I need to have a seprate function for the calculations/conversions because it would have to connect to the API and convert the strings into numbers from the textField which I already have. All I need is the title from the data selected in the pickerViews to display with the calculations in a label at the bottom of the display.

Comment: Do you understand what I am talking about or do you want me to go deeper?

Comment: So I just need the name from the data slected in that didSelect function to display in another function, but I am having a scope issue and have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me!!

Comment: Edit your question to show how you are populating the title rows of your pickerViews and give an example of the output you are trying to achieve.

Comment: It sounds like from your question that you are putting a result into a local variable in that function and then trying to access it in another function.  Instead, put the result into a property of the class.  That is, define the variable to hold the result as a class property (before any of the methods) and then you'll be able to access it from your compute function.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! what I did was take that line of code where you did your calculation, but instead of calculting them I took the "data[picker1.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]" and used that in a Label inside a diffrent function and it works PERFECTLY!!!!